# Check File Extension in Formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, formview

I have a Formview that shows data from multitables. One of its rows contains path for a file saved in project folder.

I'd like to check this file extension and corresponding in its extension I will show 
an icon for every file extension.

For example, if the file is a .txt file I will show an icon for .txt files in formview

[image]

I'd like to replace [ ~/Files/Link.txt ] with an icon

Can this be done with an if Condition in the code-behind in the formview_bound event?

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.File1.PostedFile.FileName);
if (ext==txt){
show icons with navigt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Response.Write(Path.GetExtension(@"F:\Articles\ValidationControls\ValidationControls.zip"));

To get File Name,

Response.Write(Path.GetFileName(@"F:\Articles\ValidationControls\ValidationControls.zip"));

To get File name without extension,

Response.Write(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"F:\Articles\ValidationControls\ValidationControls.zip"));